# Help with linq query

Tags: linq

I'm trying to convert a list into a different format using linq.

The (simplified) data is as follows:

```
Code Name 
----------
X    Red  
Y    Yellow
Y    Red   
X    Blue  
Z    Green
```

And the format I'd like is:

"X: Red, Blue Y: Yellow, Red Z: Green"

I'd appreciate some tips on how to progress.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: What are these types?  How exactly do you want the result to be?  A string?  What is your attempt?

Comment: The types are both strings. The attempt I've got returns "X: Red, X: Blue, Y: Yellow, Y: Red....". I can't get the grouping to work correctly. The format I'd like is: "X: Red, Blue Y: Yellow, Red Z: Green".

Comment: You should include the code you used for your attempt at this in general.  That way we could properly help you with where you went wrong and how it could be corrected and not just give you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Data> list = ...;
var query = list.GroupBy(d => d.Code, d => d.Name)
    .Select(g => g.Key + ": " + String.Join(", ", g));
string result = String.Join(" ", query);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var results = codes.GroupBy( x => x.Code)
                   .Select( g => string.Format("{0}: {1}", g.Key, string.Join(",", g.Select( c => c.Name).Distinct())))
                   .ToList();
```

Output for your sample:

```
X: Red,Blue
Y: Yellow,Red
Z: Green
```